# Generate file to download in js on the fly (while downloading)

Tags: javascript, file, browser

I have some big data set to process in browser and allow user to download results in file. The problem is that I need to generate about 100MB text file. When I try to store results in array in browser) it obviously crashes. I'd like to generate results on the fly, like using regular file writer:

```
set filename, start downloading
while not processed all data:
    push_to_file(process(data[i]))
    i++
close file
```

Is it possible? Everything must be client-side.